# How to check the version of eclipse in NVIDIA Nsight?

Tags: cuda, nsight

I have installed the `CUDA 6.5` toolkit, and I want to add some new packages into the `NVIDIA Nsight`, but how could I check the version of the `Eclipse`, because the `Eclipse` has many versions, such as `Juno`, `Indigo`, and so on. I think it needs the compatible packages. Could you help give some advice, please? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on **Installation Details** or the second square button from the left (purple circle). 
[image]

Look for **Eclipse Platform** in **Feature Name**.

[image]

The third column specifies the version number of the eclipse IDE. Check the corresponding release name ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases)). In this case, it is version 3.8 which is Eclipse Juno.